# Change visibility binding based on a property

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a list of Foo objects in my view model. Each Foo object has a property, ShouldBeVisible, that returned true or false based in some logic for whether that item should be shown to the user.

I created an IValueConverter that binds to the ShouldBeVisible property to return Visibility.Visible and collapsed.

Everything is great and I can appropriately show only the Foo items that should be shown in my StackPanel.

I now want to add a check box to my page labeled "Show all", which will bind to a property on my ViewModel. When it is checked I want to show all Foo items, no matter what ShouldBeVisible says, and if it is unchecked to follow ShouldBeVisible.

I'm unsure how to properly bind this since the IValueConverter can only be bound to one item.

Is there a way to update the visibility binding at runtime based I  whether my check box is checked?

Comment: On the change of the `ShowAll` bound property on the VireModel, could you not iterate through the list of objects and mark them all as `ShouldBeVisible` appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you could use `IMultiValueConverter` but it is not available for UWP. In this case you can use [Cimbalino Toolkit](https://cimbalino.org/).

On github is an example with this functionality:

https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/tree/master/samples/MultiBinding/MultiBinding

Install in NuGet packages: `Cimbalino.Toolkit` and `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.

Below is a simplified example. You should validate incoming parameter in VisibilityConverter.

View:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Q46430426.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Q46430426"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:Cimbalino.Toolkit.Behaviors"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="page">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowAll, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="ShowAll"></CheckBox>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Name="border" Margin="3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:MultiBindingBehavior PropertyName="Visibility" Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}" >
                                <behaviors:MultiBindingItem Value="{Binding DataContext.ShouldBeVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                <behaviors:MultiBindingItem Value="{Binding DataContext.ShowAll, ElementName=page}"/>
                            </behaviors:MultiBindingBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _showAll;
    private ObservableCollection<Foo> _items;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo(){Name = "Test1", ShouldBeVisible = true},
        new Foo(){Name = "Test2", ShouldBeVisible = false},
        new Foo(){Name = "Test3", ShouldBeVisible = true},
        new Foo(){Name = "Test4", ShouldBeVisible = false},
        new Foo(){Name = "Test5", ShouldBeVisible = true},
    };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool ShowAll
    {
        get { return _showAll; }
        set { _showAll = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

VisibilityConverter:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : MultiValueConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var shouldBeVisible = (bool)values[0];
        var showAll = (bool)values[1];
        if (showAll || shouldBeVisible) return Visibility.Visible;
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public override object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```